# (Java / Processing) How to create several instances of an object on different positions on the screen?

Tags: java, processing

I am unable to create several instances of the `waveClock` object even though I have put it in an array and marked the centre positions for each object. I would like to create 4 objects in one window, all responding to different sound frequencies/beat onsets etc

Could someone shed some light on how to go about this? I believe it may be an issue with the `centerX` and `centerY` variables in the `waveClock` class

```
ArrayList<waveClock> waveClocks = new ArrayList<waveClock>();

//global variables
float angnoise, radiusnoise;
float xnoise, ynoise;
float angle = -PI/6;
float radius;
float strokeCol = 254;
int strokeChange = -1;
int speed; //changes speed of visualisation once beat is detected?

void setup() 

  //for every waveClock we need 180 pixels width, then add 20 pixels for first gap
  size(740, 650);
  background(255);

  //code is called
  waveClocks.add(new waveClock(100, height/2, minRadius, bassColour, lowBassBand, highBassBand, numberOfLowOnsetsThreshold));
  waveClocks.add(new waveClock(280, height/2, minRadius, midColour, lowMidBand, highMidBand, numberOfMidOnsetsThreshold));  
  waveClocks.add(new waveClock(460, height/2, minRadius, highColour, lowHighBand, highHighBand, numberOfHighOnsetsThreshold));
  waveClocks.add(new waveClock(640, height/2, minRadius, veryHighColour, lowVeryHighBand, highVeryHighBand, numberOfVeryHighOnsetsThreshold));

  //set the min and max radius of each of the viz circles
 /* for (int i = 0; i < waveClocks.size(); i++) {
    //go through the arraylist of waveClocks and set the min and max radius of each circle
    waveClocks.get(i).setMinMaxRadius(minRadius, maxRadius);
  }*/

  song.play();

  beat = new BeatDetect(song.bufferSize(), song.sampleRate());

  bl = new BeatListener(beat, song);
}

void draw() {
  //clear the screen by painting it black
  //background(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < waveClocks.size(); i++) {

    //has there been a beat in the range? get(circle ID).low band, high band etc.
    if (beat.isRange(waveClocks.get(i).getLowBand(), waveClocks.get(i).getHighBand(), waveClocks.get(i).getOnsetThreshold())) {
      waveClocks.get(i).setMaxRadius();
    }
    //waveClocks.get(i).drawCircle();
    waveClocks.get(i).drawWaveClock();
  }
}
```

waveClock class in a separate tab

```
//class is an architecture blueprint
//objects are the actual buildings built from the methods (can make as many as you like)
//constructor is the builder/constructor literally
class waveClock {
  float centerX; //co-ordinates of circle's position
  float centerY; //co-ordinates of circle's position
  float radius; //avg radius
 // float minRadius; //smallest size it can be
 // float maxRadius; //biggest size it can be
  color col; //colour
  int onsetThreshold; //
  int lowBand; //looks at lowest band of frequency and makes circle sensitive to it
  int highBand; //looks at highest band of frequency and makes circle sensitive to it
  boolean onset; //has there been an onset (beat has occurred or not?)

  //the constructor 
  waveClock(float x, float y, float r, color c, int lb, int hb, int t) {
    centerX = x;
    centerY = y;
    radius = r;
    col = c;
    lowBand = lb;
    highBand = hb; 
    onsetThreshold  = t;
```

}

```
  void drawWaveClock() {
    radiusnoise += 0.005;
    radius = (noise(radiusnoise)*350) + 1;
    angnoise += 0.005;
    angle += (noise(angnoise)*6) - 3;
    if (angle > 360) {
      angle -= 360;
    } else if (angle < 0) {
      angle += 360;
    }

    xnoise += 0.01;
    ynoise =+ 0.01;
    float centerX = width/2 + (noise(xnoise)*100) - 50;
    float centerY = height/2 + (noise(ynoise)*100) - 50;

    float rad = radians(angle);
    float x1 = centerX + (radius*cos(rad));
    float y1 = centerY + (radius*sin(rad));

    float opprad = rad + PI;
    float x2 = centerX + (radius*cos(opprad));
    float y2 = centerY + (radius*sin(opprad));

    strokeCol += strokeChange;
    if (strokeCol > 354) {
      strokeChange = -1;
    } else if (strokeCol < 0) {
      strokeChange = 1;
    }
    stroke(strokeCol, 60);
    strokeWeight(1);
    line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't ever using the class-level `centerX` and `centerY` variables. Instead, you're recalculating a new `centerX` and `centerY` in the `drawWaveClock()` function.

```
float centerX = width/2 + (noise(xnoise)*100) - 50;
float centerY = height/2 + (noise(ynoise)*100) - 50;
```

These are all drawn from the center of the screen, so the waves will end up in the same position.

In the future, please try to narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Also please use proper naming conventions- classes start with an upper-case letter, for example. Good luck.

Comment: I'm unable to think of an alternative variable/value to put instead of width/2 and height/2 in the code you quoted.

Would it be wise to create 4 different classes of wave clock and input those instead. I am unsure of how to create these with an array as it didn't seem to work with my code

Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: float drawCenterX = centerX + (noise(xnoise)*100) - 50;
    float drawCenterY = centerY + (noise(ynoise)*100) - 50;
    
    // and rename accordingly the rest of the drawWaveClock() method
    // centerX, centerY come from the constructor

Comment: @ZIqbal What value are you feeding into the `WaveClock` constructor? What values do the original `centerX` and `centerY` variables hold? No, you don't need to create 4 separate classes.

Comment: Hi, the answer that villares gave ended up working. Thank you both for your advice